# How to update drizzle-box app to handle metamask no longer injecting web3?

Tags: metamask, drizzle

I was reading about the latest and greatest metamask changes, and was wondering how I can update one of my dapps based off the truffle `drizzle-box` to be compatiable with the new metamask changes.

For one of my simplier dapps, I simply changed the load listener as needed.

Will I ever have to make any changes, maybe drizzle will be smart enough to prompt access to metamask?

See:

[metamask-breaking-change](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8) I would prefer to fix this issue ahead of time.

[drizzle box](https://github.com/truffle-box/drizzle-box/issues)